# One small step for me, one giant leap for riddles!

Tags: riddle

> Gluttony at the heart of me
>   Famed worldwide for catastrophe
>   We tell ourselves we won the race
>   We delete, deny and cover all trace
>
> Our pride blinds us to stupidity
>   Attitudes towards us have no validity
>   Hide behind our mask of virtue
>   Whilst sins run amok underneath our statue
>
> Run and Hide our name Precedes us
>   our array of voices merely degrade us
>   We beat the lobster back to the sea
>   lest we forget, genocide while they flea
>
> For we were one but gained another
>   we fought our brother, disregard our mother
>   If this is appealing come join me
>   bask in my ignorance, my gluttony

Comment: "Procedes" or "Precedes"?

Comment: @McMagister Thank you for picking up on that it has been corrected

Comment: "flea" or "flee"? flea is an insect, flee is to run away.

Comment: Maybe it's only because I'm American, but ... this seems a little unnecessarily mean-spirited.

Comment: @MattMalone Please I implore you, do not take offense but if you believe it to be mean spirited fair enough. Unfortunately what I have written is the truth! Its not just because the country is a bit lame

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am

> America?

Gluttony at the heart of me

> America is famous for its consumerism

Famed worldwide for catastrophe

> Also famous for invading foreign countries/toppling their governments

We tell ourselves we won the race

> Americans won the space race, the cold war.  Also, the famous ["Mission Accomplished" banner and speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_Accomplished_speech) on the war on terror

We delete, deny and cover all trace

> NSA covert activities?

Our pride blinds us to stupidity

> American exceptionalism

Attitudes towards us have no validity
Hide behind our mask of virtue

> Americans believe strongly in the virtues of liberty and democracy

Whilst sins run amok underneath our statue

> Statue of Liberty.  The sins are probably to do with the hypocrisy of toppling democracies that don't support the West, while claiming to support democracy.

We beat the lobster back to the sea

> Lobster refers to [British soldiers](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lobsterback)

lest we forget, genocide while they flea

> Genocide of the native Americans

For we were one but gained another
we fought our brother, disregard our mother

> Brother refers to either Canada or the Confederates, mother is Britain.  "Gained another" could refer to Hawaii or Alaska.